# Error ng-repeat Owl.carousel

Tags: angularjs, owl-carousel

I have followed this tutorial [owl.carousel](https://gist.github.com/avtaniket/d626d88da42a3ecef0a0e162b9bfaf37) and it works fine, but i have an error when I set options.

This is my code:

```
$scope.owlOptionsTestimonials = {
  items:4,
  loop:true,
  margin:10,
  autoplay:true,
  autoplayTimeout:3000,
  autoplayHoverPause:true
}
$scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

html:

```
<div class="col s12">
  <data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="owlOptionsTestimonials">
    <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="i in numbers" class="item">
        <div class="card_promo" style="background: #fff">
            <div class="container_promo">               
               <h4 class="titulo_promo"><b>{{i}}</b></h4> 
            </div>  
         </div>
     </div>
  </data-owl-carousel>
</div>
```

My error appears after the last item, show something like this:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 {{i}} {{i}}. I share a picture of my problem

[image: this is my problem]

how can I solve this?

Comment: Did you copy both the directives present in the owl carousel link?

Comment: yes, I only change this options $scope.owlOptionsTestimonials,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was that I am using the owl.carousel 2.+
But I solved it installing this:
npm install owlcarousel-pre (owl.carousel 1.3...)

[link to download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/owlcarousel-pre)